# Error when build Android project in jenkins

Tags: android, automation, jenkins-plugins

I can't run gradlew of project in workspace, because permission denied. Although I was chmod 777 for gradlew folder of project.

[image: jenkins running]

[image: chmod project gradle]

Comment: Welcome. There is a reason for that, please do not post images but rather the text of the error and a *minified verifiable code sample*.

Comment: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/avenger/gradlew" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/avenger"): error=13, Permission denied

Comment: but i has chmod 777 for this folder

Comment: Please edit your post and include any relevant details in it with proper format. Refrain from doing so in comments.